# When using Javascript, is there an Apex built in to get the value of a radio group?

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-apex

Friends,

My apex page has several different radio groups, each one can have the value of Yes or No.

When the user presses a button I need to capture the values of these radio groups in the javascript processing for the page and then "do stuff" dependent on their values.

Is there an Apex Javascript API that I could utilise to obtain the values? or will I need to implement a function similiar to [this](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/finding_the_value_of_a_radio_button.php3)?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it's of interest to anyone the APEX API $f_SelectValue does what I need.

Documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/javascript_api.htm#CHDFBJDF)